# Calling php function or php file within AngularJS AJAX

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

I've been working with `AngularJs` for a while, using `PHP`/`MySql` as backend to get/send information to the dataBase.

The way I do (and it's working) is like this:

```
var myFunction = 'getUser';
$http.get('my/php/file.php?action='+myFunction).then(function(response) {
    //get data here
})

//or

var myFunction = 'addUser';
$http.post('my/php/file.php?action='+myFunction, data).then(function(response) {
    //get data here
})
```

But I also saw a lot of projects (tutorials, articles, etc..) where they call it like this (or something like this):

```
$http.get('api/user/:id').then(function(response) {
    //get data here
})

//or
$http.post('api/user', data).then(function(response) {
    //get data here
})
```

As you can see, the way I do, I declare what function I want to use, `getUser`, `addUser`, `deleteUser`, etc... But on the examples I saw, they don't do it, they just call a path reference.

What is the main difference between one method or the other? When (or why) should I use one or another?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the services that your developing

```
var myFunction = 'getUser';
$http.get('my/php/file.php?action='+myFunction).then(function(response) {
    //get data here
})

//or

var myFunction = 'addUser';
$http.post('my/php/file.php?action='+myFunction, data).then(function(response) {
    //get data here
})
```

This one corresponds to the services which has endpoints and the request and response is handled through them

Also this,

```
$http.get('api/user/:id').then(function(response) {
    //get data here
})

//or
$http.post('api/user', data).then(function(response) {
    //get data here
})
```

corresponds  to the RESTful services where the http verbs match to the corresponding resources and the services gets executed

Comment: But what woul be the main technical difference between one or another? Because I can see both can return the same type (or expected) data information. Am I right? (I'm new to backend)